# Android ZXing QR capture

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I´m trying to install the ZXing QR capture app for testing but I´m getting the error:

```
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.<clinit>(CaptureActivity.java:107)
07-26 20:15:22.667: E/AndroidRuntime(29355):    ... 15 more
```

Some idea?

Comment: What are you testing?  If you just want to test some QR Codes, then install Android's reference implementation of the Zxing project from Google Play:  Barcode Scanner

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use code in the `core/` library but did not put it into your app. But, you don't even need this code. This is by far the simplest way to add scanning: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Answer (score 0):

Is the class com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType in your build path?

Comment: I just add the core.jar to the build path. Is necessary any thing else?